# In the wake of someone's passing

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does this phrase mean?

> In the wake of my great great grandmother's **passing**.

Does **passing** mean **death** also?

If so, then why didn't they just use **death** so non native English speakers can easily get it?

Comment: Yes it does: she **passed away**. It is said that way to be tactful. The word "death" is a bit brutal to be used with people in mourning. Why should I change the way I speak to make it easy for non-natives to understand? I would if I were talking to one, or a group, specifically, but in general I just use the language as I know it.

Comment: Great. Thx. This might be useful to some.